# Pandas conditional creating columns issues

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data set,

```
import pandas as pd

df = {
  'columA':['1A','ws rank','rank','ws rank','rank','Drank'],
 'value': [ 1, 12, 34, 50, 3,2]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

**1. I want to create a column 'HP', for columnA rows that are 'ws rank' and 'rank' and 'Drank', if value is 1 then HP is 25, if value is 2 then HP is 24...etc.**
so I first created a smaller dataset to contain only those rows because my real data set is very big. I will then concatenate this dataset and the original dataset to include the 'HP' column.  But when I concatenated the datasets there are duplicated rows.  so there must be an easier way.

my code:

```
dfrank=df[df["columA"].str.contains('ws rank|rank')]
dfrank['value'] = dfrank['value'].astype(int)
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 1, 'HP'] = 25
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 2, 'HP'] = 24
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 3, 'HP'] = 23
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 4, 'HP'] = 22
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 5, 'HP'] = 21
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 6, 'HP'] = 20
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 7, 'HP'] = 19
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 8, 'HP'] = 18
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 9, 'HP'] = 17
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 10, 'HP'] = 16
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 11, 'HP'] = 15
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 12, 'HP'] = 14
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 13, 'HP'] = 13
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 14, 'HP'] = 12
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 15, 'HP'] = 11
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 16, 'HP'] = 10
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 17, 'HP'] = 9
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 18, 'HP'] = 8
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 19, 'HP'] = 7
dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 20, 'HP'] = 6
dfrank.loc[(dfrank.value > 20)&(dfrank.value <= 50), 'HP'] = 5

df2=pd.concat([df, dfrank])
```

Is there an easier way to do those conditions?
also
I keep getting this error message, **but I think i'm already using the form it's suggesting**
: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  dfrank['value'] = dfrank['value'].astype(int)
H:/Code/PythonScripts/python_work/dataset1.py:20: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  dfrank.loc[dfrank.value == 1, 'HP'] = 25
C:\Users\amywang\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:477: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s

**2. then I want to create a 'HPpoint' column that groups the 'columA' values and sums the 'HP' values, but this didn't work and returned null**

```
df2['HPpoint']=df2.groupby('columA')['HP'].sum()
```

Comment: You can replace those 2 lines of repeating code with `dfrank['HP'] = 26 - dfrank.value` or similar.  No need to have separate cases for every number!  As for the rest,  your question is too complex, with too many sub-questions and issues, and you don't have sample input data.

Comment: @John Zwinck good point! just curious if there's no pattern to these conditions is there an easier way?  but i'm still getting the same error message when i used this method you suggested.

Comment: Simplify your code.  Simplify your question.  Edit it down so you're asking one specific thing.  It's way too complex now.  Ask one thing per post, not three.

Comment: @Jessica indexing without copying the dataframe leads to this error. See my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: @John Zwinck  I asked about 2 major things which i bold and numbered. i have done so in the past with no problems, i can't separate them because they are related to each other.  it looks messy because of the nature of my code which i am asking for a simpler way, and the error message it gave me. from my past experience on stackoverflow, people have always asked to show the full error message so they can better help.    why are you giving me a vote down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas, indexing a DataFrame returns a `reference to the initial DataFrame` when you are selecting the data and storing it in new variable. So you should `copy` the dataframe to use `.loc` for the new dataframe i.e

```
dfrank=df[df["columA"].str.contains('ws rank|rank')].copy()
```

This will create new index and help you do indexing properly for the new dataframe.

Since you want to map data you can get rid of lot those lines by creating a `dictionary`, `a mask` and then `.loc`, you can fill the Nan values using `fillna` i.e

```
dicct = {1:25,2:24,3:23,4:22,5:21,6:20,7:19,8:18,9:17,10:16,11:15,12:14,13:13,14:12,15:11,16:10,17:9,18:8,19:7,20:6}
df['HP'] = 0
mask=df["columA"].str.contains('ws rank|rank')
df.loc[mask,'HP'] = df.loc[mask,'value'].map(dicct).fillna(5)
```

Output :

```
    columA  value    HP
0       1A    1.0   0.0
1  ws rank   14.0  12.0
2     rank    5.0  21.0
3  ws rank    5.0  21.0
4     rank   23.0   5.0
5    Drank   24.0   5.0
In [ ]:
```

If you want to fill the new column with `groupby sum` you can use `transform` i.e

```
df['HPpoint']=df.groupby('columA')['HP'].transform(sum)
```

Output :

```
    columA  value    HP  HPpoint
0       1A    1.0   0.0      0.0
1  ws rank   14.0  12.0     33.0
2     rank    5.0  21.0     26.0
3  ws rank    5.0  21.0     33.0
4     rank   23.0   5.0     26.0
5    Drank   24.0   5.0      5.0
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Interesting....

Not sure I fully get all your question but here is my take on the first half....

```
import pandas as pd
df = {
  'columA':['1A','ws rank','rank','ws rank','rank','Drank'],
 'value': [ 1, 12, 34, 50, 3,2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df["hp"]=0

def calc_hp(row):

    rv=0
    if row['columA'] in['ws rank','rank','Drank']:
        rv=25-int(row['value'])        
    return rv

df['hp'] = df.apply(calc_hp,axis=1)

df
```

Which returns

```
columA  value   hp
0   1A  1   0
1   ws rank 12  13
2   rank    34  -9
3   ws rank 50  -25
4   rank    3   22
5   Drank   2   23
```

I pass the whole row into the apply function, and then use (hopefully) the logic you specified.